# animating a series of images using iteration and array

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsmutablearray

I have been playing around with Xcode lately and am stuck at this stupid problem. Need help!
Okay I added 69 images to supporting files names 1.jpg,2.jpg...69.jpg. They are named so because a loop will be used to create an animation by displaying a series of images. Here is what i did.
Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myBitchViewController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *images;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;

@end
```

And implementation file:

```
#import "myBitchViewController.h"

@implementation myBitchViewController

@synthesize images;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    for (int imagenumber = 1; imagenumber <= 69; imagenumber++) {
        NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", imagenumber];
        [myString stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:myString]];
    }
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageview.animationImages = images;
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    imageview.animationDuration = 3;

    imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;

    [imageview startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    [imageview release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Now the issue is that the program doesn't throw any error but when simulator runs it just shows blank grey screen instead of animation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use `stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg"` instead of concatenating with `@".jpg"` on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could just be that your `NSMutableArray* images;` is never created. By the way, it doesn't need to be a property, you should create it just as a local variable in `viewDidLoad` - otherwise you'll keep adding more and more images to it each time the view loads.

Comment: yeah i used `NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in viewDidLoad() and it worked fine. But why didn't it work when i exposed images array as a property? I am curious!

Comment: Because the `images` array didn't exist - it was nil. If you want to use objects in properties like that you still need to create them somewhere, like in init, or lazily in their getter method.